# Stripping HTML Tags from Forum using Python/bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a (very) new Python user, and decided some of my first work would be to grab some lyrics from a forum and sort according to word frequency.  I obviously haven't gotten to the frequency part yet, but the following is the code that does not work for obtaining the string values I want, resulting in an "AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'getText' ":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.thefewgoodmen.com/thefgmforum/threads/gdr-marching-songs-section-b.14998'
wp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wp.read())
message = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "messageContent"})
words = message.getText()
print(words)
```

If I alter the code to have `getText()` operate on the `soup` object:

```
words = soup.getText()
```

I, of course, get all of the string values throughout the webpage, rather than those limited to only the class `messageContent`.

My question, therefore, is two-fold:
1) Is there a simple way to limit the tag-stripping to only the intended sections?
2) What simple thing do I not understand in that I cannot have `getText()` operate on the `message` object?

Thanks.

Comment: According to [BeautifulSoup's documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) `findall()` returns a `list` object so you will need to do something like `for i in message: print i.getText()`. Sorry for the formatting on the app.

Comment: `findAll` returns a list of elements, `getText()` only works on strings. Try printing out what has been assigned to `message` and you'll get a better view of what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` in this case is a BeautifulSoup `ResultSet`, which is a list of BeautifulSoup `Tag`(s). What you need to do is call `getText` on each element of `message` like so,

```
words = [item.getText() for item in message]
```

Similarly, if you are just interested in a single `Tag` (let's say the first one for the sake of argument), you could get its content with,

```
words = message[0].getText()
```

Comment: FWIW, BeautifulSoup switched to PEP8 guidelines and prefers get_text() now :-)

Comment: True. Similarly you should use `soup.find_all()` instead of `soup.findAll()`.